# Defining sets of commands in docker files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile in which I define two different stages like so:

```
FROM alpine:latest as base1
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY app ./
CMD ["./app"]  

FROM alpine:latest as base2
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY app ./
CMD ["./app"]
```

These stages are the same except for their names and bases.
I want to get rid of this code duplication by defining the code block once and using it in both stages but haven't found anything relevant online.

Comment: What do you mean by: "get rid". Do you need a way to check that your developers dont duplicate stages?

Comment: @JRichardsz I want to define the common code block only once and use it in both stages

Comment: I don 't know of any way to reuse snippets of a Dockerfile.  Nor would I recommend doing so if there were.  In your example, there's literally no difference between the two stages.  But usually, there would be.

Comment: I can only second @DanielFarrell comment. The parts following the `FROM...` do partially depend on the kind of base-image. Hence, I would recommend to split this containerfile into two containerfiles.